# How do I approach finding a simplified function of an 8 variable boolean function given a truth table

Tags: logic

I need  two (8 variable) boolean function that gives
$$
F_1(A,B,C,D,W,X,Y,Z) =1 \iff ABCD≥WXYZ,\\
F_2(A,B,C,D,W,X,Y,Z) =1 \iff ABCD≤WXYZ,
$$

I cant imagine using K-maps but I think that I can use the Quine-McCluskey method but that it is still unimaginably difficult manually. Is there a software, reduction techniques, or known algorithm for this that can help me?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your notation (comparators aren't used in boolean expressions), your question is quasi-trivial. Minterms are

$$ABCD+\overline{WXYZ}=ABCD+\overline W+\overline X+\overline Y+\overline Z$$

$$\overline{ABCD}+WXYZ=\overline A+\overline B+\overline C+\overline D+WXYZ$$

Comment: If my interpretation is correct, in the first minterms $F_1=1$ iff. $F_1(1111,XXXX)$ or $F_1(XXXX,0000)$ where $X$ represents the dont-care variables, which then seems lacking to me since it only considered two trivial values (the highest value for ABCD and the lowest value for WXYZ) , thank you